# stop setTimeout while moving to other page

Tags: javascript, vue.js

As per the code below my timer is working fine ,Now i want to stop the timer when the user moved to other page in between setTimeout. Thanks in advance

**TimerCount.vue(reusable component)**

```html
 <div>
 <h4>You will be forwarded to service page in {{ countDown }} seconds</h4>
   </div>
      <script>
   export default {
   data() {
        return {
         countDown : 10
        }
    },

    methods: {
       countDownTimer() {
            if(this.countDown >= 0) {
                setInterval(() => {
                    this.countDown -= 1
                    }, 1000)
            }
        }
             
    },
  
}
```

**parent.vue**

```js
  methods: {
    submitForm() {
      formService.hospital({
      FirstName: this.FirstName,
      LastName: this.LastName,
    
      description: this.description
    }) .then(response => {
      response.data;
      response;
      this.isSuccessMessage = true;
      this.isErrorMessage = false;
      this.$store.dispatch('addPickupAssistanceMessage');
    setTimeout( () => this.$router.push({ name: 'services'}),10000);
      }).catch(error => {
      this.isErrorMessage = true;
      this.$store.dispatch('addError')
      return (this.errorMessage = JSON.stringify(
        error.response.data.errorMessage
      ))
  });
     accesTimercount(){
    this.$refs.child.countDownTimer()
      },
      },
```

```html
   <div class= "alert show alertmsg" role="alert" >
  <Timercount ref="child"/>
  </div>

 <form @submit.prevent="submitHospitalAssistanceForm(); accesTimercount()" v-show=" 
     !isSuccessMessage">
  <h3>Hospital Assistance</h3>
  <div class="row gtr-uniform">
    <div class="col-6 col-12-xsmall">
    <div class="inputIcons">
      <input
        type="text"
        name="FirstName"
        value
        placeholder=" First Name"
        v-model="FirstName" autocomplete="off"
        required
      />
      <i class="fas fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </div>
       <span class="errorNotification" v-if="message.PFirstName">
         {{message.FirstName}}
         </span>
```

Comment: The general idea is that you clear the timeout / interval in your component's `beforeDestroy` hook

Comment: i have tried it but dont know from where should i have to call the clearTimeout..

Comment: i was trying inside the method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It'll be something like this, assign `setTimeout` to a variable, and then check and clear it in `beforeDestroy` hook:

```
methods: {
  submitForm() {
    // other code
    this.redirectTimeout = setTimeout(() => this.$router.push({ name: 'services'}),10000);
    // other code
  }
},
beforeDestroy() {
  if (this.redirectTimeout) {
    clearTimeout(this.redirectTimeout);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Psidom.its worked for me .i have to use this one in multiple component is there any way to do it common on use the same thing in all component.